# SSO Enabled, Forced Login via MyDomain. But as an admin am unable to login to my org

Tags: single-sign-on, mydomain

SSO Enabled, Forced Login via MyDomain. But as an admin am unable to login to my org.

Is there any way I can login. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great! Try click on Forgot Password. Salesforce will mail you a link which will let you change the password and login to your system.

**DO NOT FORGET** to change the settings once you are in, before logging out again. Else you might be required to do this again.